# How to use a value from Dataframe as constant variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2. Df2 contains a column CurrentDate which contains the current date and time, which is the same for all rows. I would like to use this CurrentDate as a constant in the following sense:

```
df1 = df1[(df1['ShiftScheduledEnd']) < df2.CurrentDate]
```

Remove the row from dataframe 1 if SchiftScheduledEnd < CurrentDate, however this gives an error because the column CurrentDate contains far more rows than df1. I thought it maybe is possible to write the CurrentDate value to a constant variable and use that one? However I did not managed to get it working correctly.

Comment: What does your df1 and df2 look like?

Comment: Sorry are you wanting `df1 = df1[(df1['ShiftScheduledEnd']) < (df2.CurrentDate)]`? you need parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence

Comment: df1 looks like :
1387   2015-07-14 23:45:00

1388   2015-07-14 23:45:00

1389   2015-07-14 23:45:00

Name: CurrentDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

The CurrentDate is the same in all rows, I would like to save this date to a variable so that I can simply use it in the rest of the code.

Comment: So how can I save a value from a DataFrame to a variable?

Comment: Please edit your data into your question, are you asking how to convert a series containing multiple values into a scalar value for comparison? So you want to do something like `curDate = df['CurrentDate'].values[0]` and then use `curDate` in your comparisons?

Comment: EdChum, that is exactly what I mean.